# MInecraft Java infinity enchant not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Whenever I put an infinity enchant on my bow it still takes up my arrows. My friend is also experiencing this issue. Is there any way to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Normal or some kind of special - spectral, tipped etc? Infinity still uses up these.

Answer (score 1):

I know this might come across as obvious, but try to make sure you have arrows in your inventory. It could also help to upgrade or downgrade your version of Minecraft if possible. This may stop you from playing on servers, but I believe it would fix the problem on singleplayer. if you can’t change the version maybe try [this article on it](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-97373).

Comment: I have definitely had the situation where I had spectral arrows, and a stack of regular arrows, and my infinity bow started using the spectral arrows first. Another somewhat obvious thing is, if you have multiple enchanted bows in your inventory, ensure that your infinity bow is the one that you are actually using. Also if you have a crossbow, and are shooting that, it will use up your arrows as well...that's all I can think of